# Input from form to url?

Tags: php

So the goal is to take the input from a form append it to the end of the URL and then return the HTML from that page. 
I am not entirely sure how to take the forms value (in this case $2) and attach it to the URL.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Metar Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <p>IACO Code: <input type="text" name="$2" value=""></p>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        <?php $html=file_get_contents("http://www.metar.mysite.net/metar?id=$2")?>
        <?php echo $_POST ["$html"];?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On submit any input from a form with method="POST" will be stored in the [$_POST global](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php). You can access it from there and append it to your URL string.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Metar Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <p>IACO Code: <input type="text" name="iacoCode" value=""></p>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        <?php 
        if (isset($_POST["iacoCode"])) {
          $html = file_get_contents("http://www.metar.mysite.net/metar?id=" . $_POST["iacoCode"]);

          echo $html;
        }
        ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Using the IF statement to check if it is set will prevent it from loading the URL with no variable.

Answer (score 0):

The way we extract data via php from a form is like below

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Metar Test</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <p>IACO Code: <input type="text" name="$2" value=""></p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    <?php $html=file_get_contents("http://www.metar.mysite.net/metar?id=$_POST['$2']")?>
    <?php echo $_POST ["$html"];?>
```